# Issue with NPM start ( React)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have just tried to view an old application of mine using npm start but it wont load keep getting the error.

```
Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Team Knowhow\development\Punk-API\node_modules\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js.
```

I tried creating a new react app and NPM start works fine so have no idea what the issue is with my old react app and why NPM start does not work.

Comment: Did you do `npm i` in the root folder before ?

Comment: did you have "yarn " installed ? if yes you need to remove it,

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed dependencies first using `npm install`.

If done already, try removing *node_modules* folder and installing dependencies again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed all dependencies including `react-scripts`!

Answer (score 0):

You've to ensure that all the `dependencies` that your application is using is mentioned in the correct manner with their correct version in your `pacakage.json` file. And if that looks alright then run

```
npm i
```

or

```
npm install
```

This command will download all the dependencies that are mentioned in your `package.json` file.

Comment: i tried to do an npm  install but it says issue with dependency tree

Comment: try removing node modules and then run this command